# Retaining tab-to-tab-stop with Emacs replace-regexp

Tags: emacs

I have a very large text file with nearly 20 columns. Unfortunately the program which produced the file did not properly handle columns which began with a -10 (it only properly spaced data which had a total of 5 characters, not 6). Essentially I ended up with something that looks like this:

```
-10.072-10.179-10.2190.002
```

I want it to look like:

```
-10.072     -10.179     -10.219     0.002
```

and was almost able to do so with:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `replace-regexp` <kbd>RET</kbd> `-10\....` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\&`<kbd>TAB</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>

When I use <kbd>TAB</kbd> however, it only replaces with a space rather than tab- ideally a tab-to-tab-stop. If I manually go to one of these situations in the file and type <kbd>TAB</kbd> it properly does a tab-to-tab-stop to align the data with the proper column. How do I retain the tab-to-stop function within the replace-regexp?

Answer (score 1):

The search and replace certainly ought to be inserting a tab. The apparent size of a tab can vary, of course, which is the only reason I can think of for it appearing to be a space. You could use `whitespace-mode` to make the difference more obvious.

As for `tab-to-tab-stop`, that's a dynamic function rather than a special kind of tab character, so you can't do that with a search and replace<sup>1</sup>. I would suggest using a keyboard macro instead, to get the same dynamic behaviour as manual typing.

- <kbd>F3</kbd>
- <kbd>M-C-s</kbd> `-10....` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `tab-to-tab-stop` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>F4</kbd>

or perhaps just: <kbd>F3</kbd><kbd>M-C-s</kbd> `-10....` <kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>

Then you can run the macro until it fails with <kbd>C-0</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>

(If you only want to run it on a portion of the buffer, you can simply narrow to the relevant region first.)

<sup>1</sup> Not strictly true, as Emacs lets you evaluate arbitrary elisp as part of a replacement pattern; but it's not just a case of calling the tab-to-tab-stop function, so the macro is really much simpler.